# JSF2+Primefaces on JBoss 5, strange browser IE8 browser issue

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, jboss, primefaces

Some background, have a web app built on JSF2+Primefaces 2.2.1, hosted on JBoss 5.

We recently delivered this web app to our client for them to test in their own QA environment.  This has been going well for a while but recently they discovered a strange issue that we are not able to reproduce in-house.

The app is fully functional, but if at *any* point the user minimizes the browser window and recovers the window by clicking on the Task bar, then the browser hangs and consistently consumes around 20% CPU until it is killed through Task Manager.  There are no script errors.

What is further strange about this is that this ONLY happens with Internet Explorer, it is not reproducible with Firefox or Chrome.  This web app contains NO third-party plugin components, no Flash, no Java applets, no video or audio players, nothing.

We ruled out a single workstation issue as this is reproducible within every workstation in their organization.  My initial reaction is that they must have an IE plugin conflict of some kind, perhaps some local client software that is causing this, but they are not convinced.

They were never very keen on JSF and are convinced that it must be a server issue.  Upon inspection of the server logs we uncovered no logged exceptions, however we did find several messages like this:

> 2011-12-05 13:24:41,162 FINE  [javax.faces.component] (ajp-XXXXXXX%2Fxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-8009-1) No renderer-type for component javax_faces_location_HEAD
>
> 2011-12-05 13:24:41,163 FINE  [javax.faces.component] (ajp-XXXXXXX%2Fxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-8009-1) No renderer-type for component j_idt15

I have been searching for similar messages and haven't really found anything.  If they do not minimize the app works perfectly fine so perhaps these log messages are a red herring?

Please give me any suggestions you may have, even if you are not sure.  At this point even if I can't figure it out I at least need to take some kind of action.  Thank you!